# How to deal with cryptography?

Tags: spaceteam

In Spaceteam, your panels may be labelled not with plain language, but pictograms or alien script. Pictograms are easier to deal with because they can be described. How do you deal with foreign text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to guess and employ a process of elimination when you're experiencing a "translator malfunction."

Sometimes it's easy: if the instruction is on your screen but specifies a number or action that doesn't appear on any of your untranslated panels, you know it's not yours and it's up to the other team members to figure it out.

If you're hearing the instruction from a team member, it might be your panel. Does a number or action match? ("Engaging" usually matches toggle switches.)

The only sure way to figure it out is to try something and notice whether it clears the instruction or not. This is obviously hard when it's not your panel, but that's why you have to work as a team!